# Google Analytics API JWT auth error in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I'm trying to setup a Node JS project that fetches data from the Google Analytics API for reporting. I'm using the `googleapis` library (latest version) and have tried following a [guide](https://flaviocopes.com/google-analytics-api-nodejs/), I think I'm missing one step.

I'm getting an error with authentication: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`

I've copied the Private Key and Client Email from my JSON file and have got them stored in my ENV file, and the following JS set up is:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const fs = require('fs')
const { google } = require('googleapis')

const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL, null, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, scopes)

const view_id = '139324249'

async function getData() {
  const response = await jwt.authorize()
  const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    'auth': jwt,
    'ids': 'ga:' + view_id,
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
  })

  console.dir(result)
}

getData()
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error, my key is stored as (obviously not adding my actual key):

```
CLIENT_EMAIL=my-client-email
PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----STUFF HERE-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I've tried some suggests on using OpenSSL to create a `.pem` file, but with that I get an Invalid signature.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried logging out the key as retrieved from ENV, compared to EG if you were to just export it from another JS file?  The error says "no start line", that seems important.

Comment: if I log `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` I indeed to see my private key, which starts off with: `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Sorted this now, thanks!

Comment: Good for you.  You should post the solution an an answer.